# Nodejs HTTP Request Body Value Console Log

Tags: node.js, express, http, request, body-parser

I'm attempting to extract a part of an HTTP POST Request Body and log it to my console using nodejs. Here is what I have so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json);

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("Example app listening on port " + PORT);
});

app.post('/events', function(req, res) {
    
    console.log(req.body);

});
```

I'm trying to log the 'challenge' value:

```
POST
"body": { 
     "type": "url_verification",
     "token": "0Rwv2qjMozpy9MSHWM2jKf0q",
     "challenge": "sW6u5bGBluzxVR79Inv04HlLGdrSxZttZ0dJrUF4E4smD8RWmbkU"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will just reference the challenge field from the body

```
consoe.log(req.body.challenge)
```

Comment: Hmmmm... I’m getting and undefined value in my console when I do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: console.log(req.body)  what does this give you. so we can see the whole object coming in.